# Vendor Information about inventory

Tags: inventory, vendor

Can magento store information about the vendors from which you acquire inventory natively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CAN it - yes... DOES it - no, not natively

Comment: Do you mean that you have to use a third party module to do it?

Comment: You either need to find an extension that might do what you want, or you'll need to create a module to do exactly what you want to do.